# Are there CPUs that perform this possible L1 cache write optimization?

Tags: caching, cpu

When the CPU with an L1 cache does a write, what normally happens is that (assuming that the cache line that it is writing to is already in the L1 cache) the cache (in addition to updating the data) marks that cache line as dirty, and will write the line out with the updated data at some later time.

One possible optimization would be to have the cache compare the contents of the write and the previous contents of the cache, and if they're the same, don't mark the line as dirty.  Because this might allow the cache to avoid write-backs on occasion, I can see how the CPU manufacturer might see this as worth the gates needed to do this logic.

My question: are there CPUs that perform this optimization?

Background as to why I'm asking: I'm writing some code that needs to have constant memory accesses; that is, someone who is able to listen into the behavior of the cache should not be able to deduce what I'm doing.  Some of my accesses are writes, and in the obvious way to implement this code, a lot of the writes will be writing the same data that's already there. I need to do the writes because, depending on the data, the data I'm writing may or may not be the same, and it's important to perform the same action regardless.  If the CPU optimizes by not actually writing a 'no-change-write', that would mean that the behavior of the cache would vary depending on what I'm doing, which would subvert my goal.

So, is there a CPU that tries to optimize writes in this way?

Comment: It's said that there are two truly difficult problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things well, and off-by-one errors.  This is an example of why the first of these is tricky.

Comment: @poncho you say that *"someone who is able to listen into the behavior of the cache should not be able to deduce what I'm doing."* Now if some CPUs implemented this "smart write-back" feature which does not invalidate the cache unless data is really updated, then by going one level further away from the CPU in the memory hierarchy, one would be able to observe the traffic/timing differences between real writes and dummy writes. **Is this what you are concerned about?**

Comment: @poncho Also your real question seems to be about implementing a better privileged/secure mode that does not leak usage info. Maybe you should ask that?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: well, there have been published cryptographical sidechannel attacks where an encryption routine could be attacked by another program running on a different core of the same CPU, by having the attack program monitor the shared cache.  I believe such a program could potentially detect whether L1 cache lines were flushed, and hence could deduce information about the program I'm interested in, if the CPU does the optimization under discussion.  I'm not talking about a 'secure mode', as I don't assume the ability to modify the CPU or the OS.

Comment: Even if this is true today, it's not guaranteed to be true tomorrow.

Comment: @poncho Yes, i know of such side-channel attacks on Intel and ARM CPUs. This confirms that Intel and ARM CPUs (current gen) do NOT implement such "smart write-back" cache feature in hardware. To mask what is being done in your program, you could continue to do unconditional writes to all potentially affected variables in your program and hope that no program running on the other core notices which variables are actually updated with new values and which are dummy writes. So this trick/approach to mask actual writes with dummy writes seems OK for now.

Comment: **See [What specifically marks an x86 cache line as dirty - any write, or is an explicit change required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417481/what-specifically-marks-an-x86-cache-line-as-dirty-any-write-or-is-an-explici)** on SO for a re-ask of this question with a serious computer-architecture answer.  (And hoping for the other answer, to save bandwidth instead of to avoid timing attacks.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From hours of searching, I wasn't able to find a CPU that uses this specific optimization. Most of the optimizations mentioned usually related to hit/miss with read/write operations and data access:

(pages 7 and )
https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa14/cse240A-a/pdf/08/CSE240A-MBT-L15-Cache.ppt.pdf

However, that doesn't mean that this optimization can't be performed. In general, it is possible to programmatically access the size of a CPU cache line. It is also possible to access current values in cache registers - but it's somewhat dangerous to do so. If you access the wrong registers at a bad time, you could be tampering with ones related to a running program. Or you could inadvertently modify the contents of the lines you're trying to read.

[Obtaining current value in register's cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437382/obtaining-current-value-in-registers-cache)

Furthermore, all of the theoretical solutions require some form of software implementation (assembler). The closest I've found relates to the ARM architecture, which appears to allow for cache manipulation. In addition to this, you would also need to know the size of a cache line for your desired CPU. You could carefully read the cache contents to a secondary location in memory, in line-sized increments, and compare it to data that is about to be written to the registers (or L1 cache lines, in this case).

[Read CPU cache contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006981/read-cpu-cache-contents)

From there, you could devise a software-based system that prevents identical rewrites. While this is a bit simplified, it is so because the solution has to be applicable for any CPU that exists.

Another possibility that I found related to Cache coherence:

[Relevant passage from a Wikipedia article about acche coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence#Coherency_mechanisms)

The main point that caught my attention, in relation to this issue, was the Snarfing description:

> It is a mechanism where a cache controller watches both address and data in an attempt to update its own copy of a memory location when a second master modifies a location in main memory. When a write operation is observed to a location that a cache has a copy of, the cache controller updates its own copy of the snarfed memory location with the new data.

In other words, there are possibly mechanisms already in place. It's just that they might not be used for the optimization you have suggested. You would have to implement software that performed the read/write comparison.

Comment: *It is also possible to access current values in cache registers - but it's somewhat dangerous to do so.*  Huh, this makes no sense.  Do you mean CPU registers?  Compiler generated or hand-written asm code uses registers to hold values that it's operating on...

Comment: If you're trying to implement this in software, you'd just have the compiler generate code that does `if (mem != x) { mem = x; }` instead of `mem = x;`.  This is only sometimes an optimization for shared cache lines in a multi-threaded program, because writing interferes with other threads reading.

Comment: "snarfing" has nothing to do with this.  It's just passive snooping.  [CPU caches use MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) so they can have coherent write-back caches.

Comment: @PeterCordes

If you find my answer distasteful, I apologize. However, it appears that you have more insight than me on the matter. So, why not answer the question yourself? My response was obviously inadequate by your standards...

Comment: I did, [on a near-duplicate of this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417481/what-specifically-marks-an-x86-cache-line-as-dirty-any-write-or-is-an-explici).

Comment: @PeterCordes I went to the page you linked, to take a look at the answers. I can see some of what you're saying. You're probably even right. But, I can also see that you talked a bit about me on the page you linked. You know, maybe you could do us all a favour and simply tell me of my mistakes directly, instead of gossiping :( This is part of why I'm taking a hiatus from SX.

Comment: Note the dates on all of those.  I commented here *while writing that answer*, pointing out the mistakes in this answer.  Then I finished that answer and posted it within a day of commenting.  I'm not trying to pick on you specifically; the other answers on this question aren't great either (so I commented on them, too.)  This was the only one I downvoted, though, because especially your 2nd paragraph doesn't make sense.  What registers are you talking about?  (and what do regs have to do with cache?)  And why do you need the size of a cache line?  (although you might as well hard-code 64B).

Comment: In summary, the OP was asking about an optimization to cache writing, which would (hypothetically) prevent the CPU from rewriting the same data to cache (assuming the data that was about to be written already existed in cache). The OP asked about a hypothetical operation, that would compare the contents of the repeated cache line to what was about to be written to cache. But, reading from cache is somewhat dangerous, due to the nature of cache.

Comment: Reading from cache doesn't have a standard x86 instruction assigned to it. Furthermore, even if allowed, simply reading the contents of cache can actually affect the contents of the cache. Therefore, you'd have to read the cache contents to a different (preferably reserved) memory location first, and then write back once you're finished doing so (similar to how one pops/pushes register values). This is assuming that the contents aren't a part of a running program/file in use (which means any process attached to the cache contents would have to be paused first before proceeding).

Comment: This other answer mentions part of what I was talking about in my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437382/obtaining-current-value-in-registers-cache


One of my older (deleted) questions lightly touched on the dangers of reading from memory (read-copy-writeback and memory mapping) as well:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357130/detecting-system-memory-from-kernel-space

Comment: Reading cache is not dangerous: that's what normal load instructions do (on cacheable memory regions).  This optimization has to be done by the CPU in hardware, so it can just read a cache line into an internal buffer.  It isn't something you'd let software do on its own, just as part of the normal operation of a store committing to cache on a CPU that eliminates silent stores, so it's totally irrelevant that x86 doesn't have special instructions for doing a read from cache specifically (without triggering a demand load if the data wasn't in cache?)

Comment: Silent-store elimination couldn't be allowed to break the atomicity of a store, so it doesn't matter what else was using that physical address.  The CPU doesn't know about "running programs", or whether the memory the CPU cache is caching is file/disk-cache or not, and it doesn't matter.  Correctness only depends on the code running the store instruction; silent store elimination doesn't change the architectural behaviour.

Comment: @PeterCordes Then, in that case, the question you were just answering over at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419108/6231921) might have some insight to this as well:

_"Currently no implementation of x86 (or any other ISA, as far as I know) supports optimizing silent stores."_ , as stated by _[Paul A. Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2467198/paul-a-clayton)_

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The questions are basically duplicates.  It would be possible to implement, but nobody does because it's too expensive to be worth the small benefit.  (Or at least neither Paul nor I have heard of it.)

Comment: I must say that you're correct on the point of possible duplicates. However, I must also state that [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006981/read-cpu-cache-contents) [Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683061/6231921) on Stack Xchange have already stated that using the CPU to programatically read its own cache could alter the contents of the cache itself. Your CPU would need to be cache aware in order to perform the cache-line comparison without causing issues at runtime. 

_I also find it necessary to say that, if this conversation must go on, must occur in a dedicated thread._

Comment: You're reading question about using CPU instructions to read cache state into architectural registers.  That's very different from the CPU's own internals reading the same cache line that it's already about to store to.  The store hardware already accesses the cache.  Of course it's "aware" of the cache; a store works by getting exclusive access to a cache line ([MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol)) and then modifying that line.  CPUs don't expose these internals in the instruction-set, but we're not talking about new instructions, we're talking about the store hardware

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71900/discussion-between-tophatproductions115-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 4):

Writing to L1 cache is a very, very time critical operation.

Writing the exact same data back seems to be rather rare. An optimisation that speeds things up in this particular case isn't going to get a lot of speedup in total.

On the other hand, this optimisation requires a comparison of old data and new data on every single write to cache memory. What makes this worse, is that it requires that the data to be written has to be actually available at the time of the write!

That is usually not the case on a modern CPU. The data to be written may still be being calculated for example. The cache can still go ahead, load the cache line if needed, mark the cache line as modified and so on, even before the calculation is finished. All the book keeping can already be performed except for the actual modification of the cache line. If you want to compare newly written result and old cache line data, that isn't possible.

As an example, if you have C code a [i] = x / y; the division x / y takes an extraordinary long time to perform on most CPUs. However, most of the work needed to handle storing the result to a [i] has happened long before the division finishes; the only thing missing is the move of eight result bytes to the cache line. An operation flushing the cache line will automatically wait until the division is finished. An operation reading a [i] will likely be redirected to get the result straight from the divider.

Comment: A cache using MESI for coherence could still do the RFO, but if the data compared the same once it was ready, leave the line in Exclusive state instead of Modified.  The real reason it's not done in hardware is that it costs extra cache reads as the data commits to cache, and would require a sort of atomic read/compare/write cycles (with optional setting of the dirty bit) that makes it suck for a pipelined implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> One possible optimization would be to have the cache compare the
>   contents of the write and the previous contents of the cache, and if
>   they're the same, don't mark the line as dirty

Won't such optimization double the time CPU needs to write something into cache? Because **each** cache line write will now be accompanied with a compare operation, which is not free.

So, actually the optimization now will depend on the very vague factor: how many times an average software rewrites its cacheable memory with the same data.

Comment: This comparison would be implemented within the CPU logic. It would not require an additional CPU operation, but the signal time might increase, which could be a problem or not.

Comment: @ziggystar Well, I am not a hardware master, but I got used to the thought that everything comes with a cost. So does compare operation against cache line. It might be fast. But this is still cost. And I think implementors decided not to pay it. May be even after some thinking and measuring.

Comment: But you are talking about time, where the cost might only be an increase in the number of gates.

Comment: @ziggystar May be you are right. I don't know what 'gates' are anyway ;)

Comment: I agree that the optimization wouldn't be free; however it would improve things (the amount of traffic being written to the higher-level caches, and eventually to main memory) a bit.  My question isn't whether this tradeoff would make sense in all cases, or even most cases; my question is whether it made sense to *some* design team - whether there exists a CPU that does it.

Comment: @ziggystar: This isn't just more gates. When data is sent to the cache, normally the process of sending the data can mark the cache line as modified. With this "optimisation", the old data and the new data must both pass through these gates which will cause some delay, and only then can the cache be invalidated. You have to squeeze all this into one processor cycle, otherwise writing to a cache line suddenly takes two cycles. And now to make things more complicated, consider what happens when I write eight consecutive words to a cache line.

Comment: And each of these writes delays the decision whether the cache line is modified. So when the second write happens, the cache line doesn't know whether it is modified or not (yet). This is going to be fun.

Comment: You could do it without throughput reduction, but it would require an extra cache read port, and make pipelining harder.  You'd build a cache that did a read/compare/write cycle instead of just write, and could conditionally leave the line in Exclusive state instead of Modified (of [MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol).  Doing it this way (instead of checking while it was still Shared) would still invalidate other copies of the line, and have to be done atomically (can't lose the cache line between the read and the write, when you get it again the compare result is stale).

Comment: @gnasher729: See [another version of this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417481/what-specifically-marks-an-x86-cache-line-as-dirty-any-write-or-is-an-explici), where there's a very good computer-architecture answer from Paul Clayton.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: A more comprehensive version of this answer is [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63143231/149138) and I recommend you read that one for the most up-to-date information.**

I found evidence that some modern x86 CPUs from Intel, including Skylake and Ice Lake client chips, can make this optimization, but at the L2 <-> L3 boundary, not at the L1<sup>1</sup>, in at least one specific case:

**An all zero cache line is written to with additional zeroes, so that it remains fully zero.**

That is, a "zeros over zeros" scenario.

For example, this plot shows the performance (the circles, measured on the left axis) and relevant performance counters for a scenario where a region of varying size is filed with 32-bit values of either zero or one, on Skylake client:

[image: SKL Store Elimination]

Filling with zeroes both performs better and shows about half of the write bandwidth to DRAM. On Ice Lake, the optimzation takes effect more often and the write bandwidth drops close to zero.

You can find more detail on [the above-mentioned StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63143231/149138), and in [this blog post](https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2020/05/13/intel-zero-opt.html) where I cover it in more detail. There is an addendum for Ice Lake, which as mentioned exhibits this effect more strongly [here](https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2020/05/18/icelake-zero-opt.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, it is possible that the "is all zero" state is detected at the L1 and propagated outwards for ultimate use at the L2 <-> L3 boundary.

Comment: (re: discussion on the SO version of this: I wouldn't worry about keeping this version in sync.  Maybe just make the link to the SO version more prominent, and point out that it also has updates, like where the is-all-zero state is detected, so future readers should really *just* read that if a quick skim of this looks interesting at all.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - good idea, I put another link at the top.